# How can I start solr from a php script executed by Apache?

Tags: php, apache, solr

I'm trying to start solr from a php script executed by apache (mod_php).

After doing the classic ping to check if solr is up, I tried to execute with:

`exec("/opt/solr-6.6.5/bin/solr start > /dev/null 2>&1");`

but I always get the error:

`"nohup: can not detach from console: No such file or directory"`

in /var/logs/apache2/error_log.

If I run the simple php script from cli:

```
 <?php
    exec("/opt/solr-6.6.5/bin/solr start > /dev/null 2>&1");
```

it works perfectly and solr goes up.
I tried in every way, with nohup, even with an external script:

```
<?php
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid < 0) // error
    exit;
else if ($pid) // parent
    exit;
else // child
{
    $sid = posix_setsid(); // creates a daemon

    if ($sid < 0)
        exit;

exec("/opt/solr-6.6.5/bin/solr start > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
```

but I cannot run the standard solr script from within Apache mod_php.
Is there someone who can help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Apache user usually www-data probably doesn't and shouldn't have the permission to do this. I would suggest you don't start Solr this way and instead configure it as a service using systemd or similar.

Comment: I'd recommend to start Solr as a service. After executing `bin/install_solr_service.sh` you should be able to `sudo service solr start` as long as you use CentOS, Debian, Red Hat, SUSE or Ubuntu. [Click here for details](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/taking-solr-to-production.html)

Comment: Ok thanks, I know that solr must starts as a service but the question is: why I can start solr under Linux in that way, even if it isn't the right way to start it, while I can't do it with OS X where I get the error "nohup: can not detach from console: No such file or directory" ?